# timeshift: not enough disk space error backing up 16GB system files to 4TB drive

Tags: backup, timeshift

I'm on a Mate 20.04 system.  I've been using Duplicity for backups, but I'm looking at setting up Timeshift for system backups.  However, it's telling me that my target for the snapshots (a 4TB raid volume with over 3TB of free space) doesn't have enough disk space to hold a 16.4GB snapshot.  However, if I select my 852GB root partition on the SDD drive (808 GB free), it's happy.  I just don't want to write the system snapshots to the root partition.

I've dug around google and the like, but all I've been able to find is issues with Timeshift including folders that most people didn't expect, so the estimated snapshot size was larger than they thought it should be.  However, in my case, it looks like it only wants 16.4GB for the snapshot and thinks that >3TB isn't enough for it.

Timeshift Settings

[image: timeshift_settings]

disks GUI

[image: disks_GUI]

Is this a problem with Timeshift not being able to handle TB values properly?  3TB would overflow a 32-bit integer if looking at raw byte size, and even looking at the number of 1K blocks available would set the high-order bit, so I'm wondering if that's what is happening internally.  Probably grasping at straws there, but it's the only thing I can think of at this point.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is dm-0 mounted read write? The TimeShift settings dialogue is not showing any free space. Just a point of information, TimeShift is not really a backup solution. It’s more of a roll back system to get a broken installation working again. It’s great used in conjunction with another backup solution for data.

Comment: Understood about Timeshift being meant as a roll-back system vs a backup system.  I was more focused on trying to figure out why it thinks that 3+TB isn't enough space to write a 16GB snapshot.

The device is mounted RW.  It's actually mounted at /local, and user home directories are in a folder under that and served via NFS.  Not sure why it shows it mounted at /home/dwight.  Guess it doesn't understand autofs mount points?

    /dwight

Comment: Suggest you try mounting your 4TB array with fstab rather than autofs and troubleshoot from there. Without knowing much about your use case why are you using autofs and what looks like a raid 0. If you have good reason then fine but it's usually best not to over complicate things. I cannot find anything on the bug tracker to suggest TimeShift cannot cope with large drives so I don't think that's the answer

Comment: The raid 5 disk is hard mounted (via fstab) on /local.  The only things that are mounted via autofs are user home directories from /local/home (NFS mounts).  That way they are available regardless of what machine they actually log in to.  I don't know why TimeShift is showing the autofs mount point instead of the hard mount point from fstab.

Comment: I save my snapshots to my root partition. It protects me against updates that mess up the machine. I have other solutions that protect against device failure. You have to be able to write to /timeshift on the target device perhaps there is something that prevents that in your setup

Comment: I don't really want to get into a discussion over where is the best place to put the snapshots.  I'm just trying to determine why TimeShift is having problems with my 4TB Raid 5 disk.  It is writeable, and is mounted by fstab at /local.  But for some reason TimeShift thinks that there are 0 bytes available when it actually has over 3TB free.

Comment: I've done a bit of testing with a virtual machine to which I added a new virtual disk. If I get to the select snapshot location and select as per your picture but then cancel the wizard I find  the desired location is mounted at /run/timeshift/backup. However it may also be mounted elsewhere which you can check with "mount -l -t ext4". Apps like disks and commands like lsblk only report a single location. Timeshift will create a directory /run/timeshift/backup/timeshift where the snapshots are kept. Might be worth seeing if you are getting these mounts and have the permissions to write there

Comment: I've moved on from this by picking up a 64Gb USB thumbdrive.  TimeShift seems to be happy with that and will create the snapshots.

Comment: Hit return too quick:
For completeness though, I went in to the settings and set the location back to my Raid drive and ignored the complaint.  mount -l -t ext4 shows /dev/mapper/isw_bajhbjdfhi_Volume0 on /local, /home/dwight, and /run/timeshift/backup.  When I set the location to the thumbdrive, it shows up as /dev/sdf1 on /recovery (the mountpoint I set) and on /run/timeshift/backup.  I wonder if it doesn't like the /dev/mapper device?

Comment: Thanks for the update. It’s a bit of a mystery.